# adding a pop up to a form in JSP

Tags: jquery, html, css, hibernate, jsp

I am learning the front end design and using Hibernate with Structs2. 
What I want to do is that once an user clicks on "delete" button, a window/modal shows up asking the user if he/she wants to delete".
The window only shows two button, "delete" and " cancel". 
If the user clicks on the delete button, the window closes up and redirects to the success page. If the user clicks on the "cancel" button, the window disappears and go back to the original page.
What I got so far in my jsp file :

```
<s:form id="createForm" method="post" action="deleteConfirm"  theme="xhtml">
  <s:hidden name = "userId" value = "%{userId}" />
  <s:submit value="Delete" type="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

This code works fine but it does not have the modal/window. May anyone tell me how to add a simple modal to this existing code. 
My structs2 xml :

```
 <action name="deleteConfirm" class="SkillAction" method="execute">
  <result name="input">UserInfo.jsp</result>
  <result name="success">Success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of Javascript/css libs that provide this functionality. Check out the struts 2 jQuery plugin

https://code.google.com/archive/p/struts2-jquery/

Or build your own:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp